# Add - In a string in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have a scenario where I have to add `-`

Case Sample 1 Input `9:30 PM 7:30 AM` And I want the output to be `9:30 PM - 7:30 AM`

Case Sample 2 Input `2:30 AM 8:30 PM` And I want the output to be `2:30 AM - 8:30 PM`

Case Sample 3 Input `2:30 AM 8:30 AM` And I want the output to be `2:30 AM - 8:30 AM`

Case Sample 4 Input `2:30 PM 8:30 PM` And I want the output to be `2:30 PM - 8:30 PM`

How Can I achieve this using the js function?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: since you have a fixed input style you can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: @AmitChauhan Though of the logic, to Add `-` after 7th char(including space) So at 8th position adding `-` would work. But not sure feasible or not.

Comment: `'9:30 PM 7:30 AM'.replace('M ','M - ')` is sufficient. Or if you really must use a regular expression: `'9:30 PM 7:30 AM'.replace(/([AP]M )/,'$1- ')` and there is `'9:30 PM 7:30 AM'.split('M ').join('M - ')`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addDash(s){
  let m = s.indexOf("M")
  return `${s.slice(0,m+2)}-${s.slice(m+1)}`
}

console.log(addDash("9:30 PM 7:30 AM"))
console.log(addDash("2:30 PM 8:30 PM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addDash2(ele){
  return ele.match(/.{1,8}/g).join('- ');
}
console.log(addDash2("9:30 PM 7:30 AM"))
console.log(addDash2("2:30 PM 8:30 PM"))
console.log(addDash2("2:30 AM 8:30 AM"))
console.log(addDash2("2:30 AM 8:30 PM"))
```